# Does defining a class in the constructor of another python class cause a memory leak?

Tags: python, garbage-collection

Not sure if I am doing something obviously wrong, but the following Python-code seems to be leaking memory:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        class B(object):
            pass

for i in range(0, 100):
    a = A()
a = None
```

From my understanding of Python's garbage collection, all objects created should be garbage collected at the end of this example program. However, there are objects on the heap left floating around. The number of objects  grows with the number of loops, but does so sub-linearly.

If I comment the inner class `B`, it's not leaking anymore.

This dummy example has been tested using `guppy` and Python 2.7.12. I did not test it using Python 3, but we observed the same effects running our software that initially yielded the bug under Python 2 and 3.

Comment: I tested it on Python 2.6.6 and 3.6.0. On Python 2, `gc.collect()` returns 600, on Python 3 it returns 599.

Comment: _"However, there are objects on the heap left floating around."_ How can you tell?

Comment: Running with mprof shows a constant use of memory after a certain point in time, stopping at 40MiB, there's no memory leak going on here.

Comment: FWIW, details of how CPython's memory management works can be found in the [c-api docs](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/memory.html).

Comment: Why does each instance of A need its very own B class definition? Why not just define B as a class attribute of A?

Comment: @PM2Ring I don't think that is relevant to this discussion, it seems clear the problem isn't that they wouldn't know to do that, but that the results they got from an arbitrary nested constructor class def don't make sense.

Comment: @snb Need to check with mprof then. Maybe I simplified the example too much. We certainly are having a memory leak in our software caused by a class defined in a constructor.

Comment: @Kevin I've used guppy/heapy.

Comment: @arnuschky you need to do way more than 100 iterations to see it isn't leaking in mprof.   Also I'm using python 3.6, and range doesn't do the same thing in 3.x in 2.x, its possible what you are actually seeing is the range array size increasing in size every iteration (in python 2.x it creates a list, not a range object).

Comment: I've tested again and failed to reproduce it. It appears that I misread guppy's results previously.

I don't have the time right now to re-investigate - the code that certainly reproduced the problem is much longer than the example above and involves an external library.

What shall we do - delete this question and I re-post if I can reproduce the problem using only the standard lib?

Comment: There's no need to delete the question. I agree that there probably _isn't_ an actual memory leak, but I'd still like to know what's _really_ going on. ;)

Comment: I can't reproduce this; I used `guppy` and `objgraph` in Python 2.7 and do not see anything suspicious left on the heap after running your sample. Perhaps you can give us more details on how you determined the issue and what you see? Include exact version numbers too.